# Can't seem to compile chromium embedded framework on Mac

Tags: objective-c, chromium, xcode6, chromium-embedded, osx-yosemite

Trying to compile Chromium Embedded framework on Yosemite Developer Preview gives me a few errors involving `[NSApp setDelegate:self];` cefsimple_mac.mm with the error:

cefsimple_mac.mm:93:22: Incompatible pointer types sending 'SimpleAppDelegate *' to parameter of type 'id'

Obviously not a solution, but commenting this out provides more of these errors in the code as well.

I looked up NSApp setDelegate in the Mac Developer Pre-Release library, and it seems that it no longer works as intended in 10.10 (I don't want to say deprecated because I am going off of memory, and just know it was crossed out).

Does anyone know of a way I could fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried CEF on 10.10,  but looks like it's API change of NSApp in 10.10,

Here is a similar issue in Qt:

[https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-39644?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-39644?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel)

So the fix maybe replacing

`[NSApp setDelegate:self]`

with

`[[NSApplication sharedApplication] setDelegate:self];`

Comment: Now I'm getting this:      Incompatible pointer types sending 'SimpleAppDelegate *' to parameter of type 'id<NSApplicationDelegate>'      Obviously I need to get the delegate of the class, but I am not sure how to.

Comment: Change line number 14 of cefsimple_mac.mm from "@interface SimpleAppDelegate : NSObject" to "@interface SimpleAppDelegate : NSObject<NSApplicationDelegate>"